JSONPath with multiple filter expressions
I have a JSON with the following structure:
{
    "markets": {
        "US": {
            "homes": [
                {
                    "type": "house"
                },
                {
                    "type": "multifamily"
                },
                {
                    "type": "townhouse",
                    "hoa": {
                        "features": "dog park, covered parking"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "house"
                },
                {
                    "type": "multifamily"
                },
                {
                    "type": "townhouse",
                    "hoa": {
                        "features": "pool, snow removal"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

I need a JSON path (using JSONPath 2.4) that can return the value "pool, snow removal".
This example is hypothetical, but the "pool, snow removal" value is always the last entry of "type": "townhome" in the "homes" list (not always necessarily the last entry in homes, but the last one of type townhome), and it always contains "pool" in the features.
I've tried using a filtering expression to filter by type == "townhouse", but can't get a second filter to work.
I've tried returning the last element (using [-1] and [@.length-1]) but haven't had success with that either. For example:
$.markets.US.homes[?(@.type == 'townhouse')][-1]
$.markets.US.homes[?(@.type == 'townhouse')][-1:]
and
$.markets.US.homes[?(@.type == 'townhouse')][@.length-1]
all return no records in https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/# and https://jsonpath.com/
Same as $.markets.US.homes.hoa[-1] (and similar permutations) relying on the fact that only the townhouse entries have the "hoa" field.
I've tried using "contains" and "in" as part of the filtering expression to look for features with "pool" in the value, but no luck there either. E.g.,
$.markets.US.homes..hoa[?(@.features contains "pool")]
$.markets.US.homes..hoa[?("pool" in @.features)] (although this one I would expect wouldn't work because the entire "features" isn't just "pool")
What JSONPath expression can I use to retrieve the final entry features where the type == "townhouse"?

What you're looking to do can't be done with pure JSON Path.
Your $.markets.US.homes[?(@.type == 'townhouse')] (without the [-1]) is the closest you'll get, and that will return all "townhouse" entries.  You'd need to get the one you need in code.
The extra [-1] that you're adding doesn't work because it doesn't align with the structure of the data.  The path above returns a collection of objects, then the [-1] tries to operate on each of those objects.  Since [-1] only operates on arrays, it returns no values.
As an alternative, you could do a two-stage query.  The first stage is the query above.  Then you'd render the results of that back into a JSON array and feed that into a new query with the path $[-1].  In this case, the data actually is an array, so the [-1] works as you expect.

Ah the two-stage query might work for what I'm doing, and hadn't thought of that. Thank you, I'll give this a try!
